# I'm having trouble catching a NullPointerException in android

Tags: android, multithreading, exception

I have a Service class called UpdaterService. The following is my onStartCommand() method:

```
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
       if(Constants.DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "onStarted");
       updater = new Updater();
       try {
           updater.start();
       } catch(NullPointerException e) {
           Stuff.showErrorMessage();
       }

       return Service.START_STICKY;
}
```

updater is a custom object of class Updater which extends Thread. The following is my the exception I'm getting:

```
08-12 12:19:49.708: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1995): Uncaught handler: thread Updater exiting due to uncaught exception
08-12 12:19:49.708: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1995): java.lang.NullPointerException: HostActivity not instantiated
    at com.morten.app.klepprc.services.UpdaterService$Updater.run(UpdaterService.java:135)
```

This causes my application to crash. At line 135 of UpdaterService.java:

```
if(application.getHostActivity() == null) {
   throw new NullPointerException("HostActivity not instantiated");
}
```

How come the exception isn't being handled in my catch block? All feedback appriciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your `start();` method is non-blocking.

The exception happened in run() method, which is on a different thread ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The run() method in which the exception is thrown is the run() method of the Updater class thread.

Comment: Yes, it's on a different Thread than where your try-catch is... Try putting the try-catch in the run method.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me but now I'm getting a different error: `08-12 13:13:26.118: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2089): Uncaught handler: thread Updater exiting due to uncaught exception
08-12 13:13:26.118: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(2089): java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
        at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
        at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:68)
        at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:231)
        at com.morten.app.klepprc.utility.Stuff.showErrorMessage(Stuff.java:94)`

Comment: That's an error in `tuff.showErrorMessage()` method. You'll have to see what that method does. To me, it seems like that method is attempting to write to the UI, but you're not on the UI thread. You'll have to switch back to the UI thread before doing anything related to the UI.

Comment: It appears the new error is related to me trying to make a Toast off the UI thread. Managed to fix it. Thanks again!